# Bing maps vs Bing maps API

Tags: bing-maps

I have a question, searching a local business on Bing maps results in detail information about the business for instance its phone, url and hours of operations. I didn't find a way to get similar attributes (phone, url, hours of operations etc) by Bing maps API. My question is it just me, who is unable to find a way to extract such info or there is no way (through Bing maps API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected. The Bing Maps website is just like any other company that uses the Bing Maps API's. They use the API's to provide mapping functionality and then add their custom functionality on top. A lot of the rich business listing data that you see on the Bing Maps website is sourced from other companies such as Yelp, Four Square or Trip advisor, but they only allow the Bing Maps to use this data in their 1st party apps (i.e. Bing Maps website) and not in the developer API's as these companies already have developer API's. This is the primary reason why you will see more data on the Bing Maps website than you will in the API. You will find that this is also the case with Google Maps as well.